# How to make sure that I only sell an item if I have enough copies of that item in store?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a dummy database for a shop for studying purposes.

In this simple database there is a table **Item** to store different items and I take note of how many copies of that item I have in the *AvailableQuantity* field.
There is also a **Purchase** table to record the purchases, which are relative to one type of item, but you can buy multiple copies of that item using the *Quantity* field.

```
CREATE DATABASE SHOP;
USE SHOP;

CREATE TABLE Item (
    ID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    Price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    AvailableQuantity INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Purchase (
    ID INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
    Date DATE, 
    Item VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Item) REFERENCES Item (ID)
 );
```

I am not sure how to make sure that x, where x is the quantity of the item being bought, is less than the *AvailableQuantity* of the relative item. In other words, I want to sell an item only if I have enough pieces of that item.

I tried with the following constraint but I guess I can't query inside constraints (I get this response: *Error Code: 3815. An expression of a check constraint 'Disponibilita' contains disallowed function.*).

```
 ALTER TABLE Purchase
    ADD CONSTRAINT ItemAvailability 
    CHECK (Purchase.Quantity <= (SELECT I.Quantity 
                                 FROM   Item I, Purchase P
                                 WHERE  I.ID = P.Item));
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Simply a `AvailableQuantity >= 0` constraint? I.e. let the items table ensure availability.

Comment: What if the customer wants to buy 3 pieces of an item? Then, even if I had 1 piece (1 is >= 0) I would record the purchase. Hope I've been enough clear.

Comment: `1 - 3 = -2`, i.e. constraint violation. You have to do it in the same transaction - of course!

Comment: Imagine your CHECK is logically correct. You have `Item.AvailableQuantity = 3` for some `Name`. You create TWO rows in `Purchase` with the same `Name` and `Quantity = 2` in each row... and your CHECK will allow this! The assumption that the CHECK is correct is erroneous.

Comment: That's right! Thanks a bunch, jarlh and Akina. Jarlh, your solution is a lot simpler but most of all effective. Could you guys suggest me (or tell me what topic I should  study) how to decrement AvailableQuantity of a value x when x pieces of item are bought?